# Any trick to make a query that ouputs no row when certain conditions are satisfied and a row when they are not (without subselects)?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

Maybe it's too obvious, but I am sure it has to be a simple way to do that

```
SELECT 'Not Contained Yet' AS FlagRow
FROM (
    SELECT 'Already Contained'
    FROM MyTable t
    WHERE t.id=? 
    AND CURDATE()=t.date  
    LIMIT 1
) aux
HAVING COUNT(*)=0
```

That simply returns no results if the register is already in the database (by id,date) and returns a row with the message 'Not Contained Yet' if it does not exist.

Any way to query that particularity without using subselects? I just need a single row with gibberish as it acts as a trigger for starting my ETL in case there are no entries for that day and id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this with `having`:

```
SELECT 'Not Contained Yet' AS FlagRow
FROM MyTable t
WHERE t.id = ? and CURDATE()=t.date
HAVING COUNT(*) = 0;
```

Comment: @user1352530 . . . Probably not stupid.  SQL is a tricky language, and we all miss helpful things now and then.

Answer (score 1):

Using `count()` you get `0` if it does not contain the record

```
SELECT count(*) as contains_count
FROM MyTable t
WHERE t.id = ? 
AND DATE(NOW()) = t.date
```

Comment: Thanks but I need no results specifically if the conditions are met, since any row acts as a trigger for my ETL

Comment: Can a `0` not act as a trigger?

Comment: No because I execute next step for each incoming row

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN count(*) = 0 THEN 'Not Contained Yet' ELSE null END CASE
FROM MyTable t
WHERE t.id=? 
AND CURDATE()=t.date
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it returns a row (a null one)